# How can I prevent select() from retrieving an empty dataframe when there are no matches?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would expect the following code to: transform `cars` in a tbl_df *then* exclude all the columns that start with "variable"; thus basically to return `cars`

```
tbl_df(cars) %>% 
select(-starts_with("variable"))
```

Is there any way I can adjust this function to retrieve cars instead of an empty dataset?
The reason why I am doing this apparently meaningless operation, is that the function is nested in a loop where columns starting with `variable` might or might not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe by mentionning all possible columns earlier in the expression:

```
tbl_df(cars) %>% select(1:ncol(.), -starts_with("variable"))
```

Comment: Integrating @G.Grothendieck's reply, I would suggest `everything()` instead of `1:ncol(.)`

Comment: I take back what I have just said, `everything` works for this example but not in my original script, thus I guess `1:ncol()` is a more generalizable solution.

Comment: @Dambo, `everything()` works in every example I tried.  Can you provide a reproducible example in which it does not work?

Answer (score 2):

Try `setdiff`:

```
# this returns all columns
tbl_df(cars) %>% select(setdiff(everything(), starts_with("variable")))

# this returns all columns except the "dist" column
tbl_df(cars) %>% select(setdiff(everything(), starts_with("dist")))
```